# FPDF file ---> send via CURL automatically NOT with file upload

Tags: php, api, pdf, curl, fpdf

Hi I have managed to successfully generate a FPDF pdf file from my form submission. I have then POSTED it via CURL to an API endpoint.
This 'file' shows inside the CRM system where supposed go but I cannot open it. 
I believe this is not the file at all and it is not being passed stored/grabbed properly.

Thanks

See below code:

```
$noteTitle = (isset($_POST['noteTitle']) ? $_POST['noteTitle'] : null);
$noteBody = (isset($_POST['noteBody']) ? $_POST['noteBody'] : null);

require("fpdf/fpdf.php");
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont("Arial", "B", 16);
$pdf->Cell(0,100, "Note Title: {$noteTitle} \n", 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(0,100, "Note Body: {$noteBody}", 1, 0, 'C');
$filename="testFPDF.pdf";
$pdf->Output($filename,'F');  

$headers2 = array(
    "authorization: Basic xxx",
    "content-type: multipart/form-data",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "postman-token: xxx"
);   

$file_name_with_full_path = 'C:/localhost/insightly-php/testFPDF.pdf';
$timeout = 30;
$target_url = "https://api.insight.ly/v2.1/Notes/?c_id=" . $noteID . "&filename=" . $filename;
$parameters =  array(
    'FILE_ATTACHMENTS' => '@' . $file_name_with_full_path,
    'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/pdf'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");    
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"");
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,10);
//curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false );
//curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
//curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC );
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

File contents are:

```
--------------------------xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FILE_ATTACHMENTS"

@C:/localhost/insightly-php/testFPDF.pdf
--------------------------xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx--
```

Comment: did you test the file before sending it? did you try comparing the filesize on both sides?

Comment: Hi there. Yes the pdf file is fine in my local directory. File sizes are different. So it is not the actual file sitting in the CRM but rather a tmp file the CRM is generating from the curl_url. I can post the file with a manual file upload input field but not automatically how I would like it in my above code. I tried creating a new CURLFILE to break it up like this $cfile = new CURLFILE($_FILES[$pdf]['tmp_name']...) but I understand $_FILES is only for file upload. Thanks

Comment: well.. that narrows it down a little, but the issue could still be on either side. you should post the receiving code as well.. good chance it is he curl tho.. are you posting this to an endpoint that is already recieving from another script?

Comment: CURLOPT_POST takes a bool, should change to 1 or true, but don't think that's the issue

Comment: also, you need to remove the json_encoding, should be an array not a json string..

Comment: you should probably remove CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST as it's redundant and there's a warning not to use it in the manual

Comment: at least for debugging you should also remove the timeout until you're sure the request isn't just timing out.. that could explain the issue

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I have just done a get test in POSTMAN and the CONTENT_TYPE is multipart/form-data instead of application/pdf   "FILE_ATTACHMENTS": [
      {
        "FILE_ID": 71606220,
        "FILE_NAME": "testFPDF.pdf",
        "CONTENT_TYPE": "multipart/form-data",
        "FILE_SIZE": 66,
        "FILE_CATEGORY_ID": null,
        "OWNER_USER_ID": 1005179,
        "DATE_CREATED_UTC": "2016-01-07 03:36:09",
        "DATE_UPDATED_UTC": "2016-01-07 03:36:09",
        "URL": "/fileattachments/71606220"
      }
    ],

Comment: Hi thanks, I have made those edits you suggested and also changed the header content type to application/pdf which came back in postman as "CONTENT_TYPE": "application/pdf; boundary=------------------------bd31df8e4025688c". but still cannot open the file inside CRM. Don't understand why header should be changed to application/pdf instead of the $parameter content type. ta

Comment: Hey I figured the problem out!! Convert the output of the fpdf as a string $doc = $pdf->Output($filename,'S');  then decode it before sending the curl var_dump(json_decode($doc, true)); will update/ post answer. thanks for your help

Comment: @RRowan : Either please post your solution as an answer below and accept after 48 hrs to gain valuable reputation points, or delete this answer please. Don't make people read thur 10 comments to find the solution. Thanks and Happy New Year.

Comment: Hi I have posted the answer below. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I managed to get this working. I am not sure if this is the best way of doing it but it worked.

It was to convert the output of the fpdf as a string $doc = $pdf->Output($filename,'S'); then decode it before sending the curl var_dump(json_decode($doc, true)); & also make the header content type "application/pdf"

```
$noteTitle = (isset($_POST['noteTitle']) ? $_POST['noteTitle'] : null);
$noteBody = (isset($_POST['noteBody']) ? $_POST['noteBody'] : null);

//FPDF
require("fpdf/fpdf.php");
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont("Arial", "B", 14);
$pdf->Cell(0,50, "Note Title: {$noteTitle}", 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(0,50, "Note Body: {$noteBody}", 1, 0, 'C');
$filename="testFPDF.pdf";
$doc = $pdf->Output($filename,'S');     

///////////FIRST POST REQUEST////////////
$orgID = 70239678;
$addNote = (object)array(        
        "TITLE" => "$noteTitle",
        "BODY" => "$noteBody ",
        "LINK_SUBJECT_ID" => "$orgID",
        "LINK_SUBJECT_TYPE" => "Organisation"              
);   
$addNote = $i->addNote($addNote); 

///////////GET NOTE ID////////////
$orgNotes = $i->getNotes(array("orderby" => 'DATE_CREATED_UTC'));
foreach ($orgNotes as $note) {        
      $noteID = $note->NOTE_ID;          
}

///////////SEND ATTACHEMENT////////////         
$headers2 = array(
    "authorization: Basic xxx",
    "content-type: application/pdf",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "postman-token: xxx"
);       

$target_url = "https://api.insight.ly/v2.1/Notes/?c_id=" . $noteID . "&filename=" . $filename;

var_dump(json_decode($doc, true));
$parameters = array(
    'FILE_ATTACHMENT' => $doc  
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

If anyone is interested this is my solution for using **file upload** instead of the fpdf send solution. [Multipart form file upload POST PHP cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34604602/multipart-form-file-upload-post-php-curl/34624025#34624025)